# Rails ActiveRecord Query a field based on word contains but not partial word

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sql-like

I know we have LIKE option to search partial word, exact word match and also word contains (but having some problem, let me explain that below)

```
 User.where("name like ?", "%john%")  
 # above code will search the name column and it will return records even if it 
   matches the character partially i.e "joh" also return a record.

 User.where("name like ?", "john")
 # above code will return a record if 'john' word is in the name column. 
   It will match the exact word.

 User.where("name like ?", "% john %")
 # this will return a record if name column contains 'john' text i.e "Sample john victor".
   But if a record has "John victor" then it won't find this record because '% john %' 
   can only match middle of the words except first and last word in the name column 
   since we having space in both front and end of the word in our search i.e "% john %"
```

Can someone help me to find a record based on word contains in a string of one column in a Table?

Comment: What do you want to obtain?

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify which database you're using and it's possible different databases allow different forms of matching. E.g. in postgres you could use [`SIMILAR TO`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-matching.html)

For a straight SQL LIKE I think you'll need to do several options ORed together.

E.g.

```
User.where("(name = ?) or (name like ?) or (name like ?) or (name like ?))", 
         'john'
         '% john %', 
         'john %', 
         '% john')
```

That'll get values that are 'john', that inclued 'john', that start with 'john' and that end with 'john' respectively.

That might be pretty slow depending on the data you're querying but I think it'll achieve what you want.